# Certificate Verification Error for localhost: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, wso2, openid-connect

I'm following this readme: https://github.com/nicodewet/template-spring-boot-oauth2-wso2-is

I do everything like in link above but when I click login I got error:

502 Bad Gateway

Certificate Verification Error for localhost: unable to get local issuer certificate (errno: 20, depth: 0)

I'm not sure where is the problem, I tried to everything and still same problem... How to solve this problem?

Comment: do you get the error from the application or do you have a proxy server set-up? Could you please post the whole stacktrace? Does you application trust the certificate of the wso2is? (importing the wso2carbon certificate into the JVM's truststore is not a very good idea from security perspective though)

Comment: I get error from application, when I type localhost:8080 and click "login" button. There is no stack trace from IDE. I done steps from this readme, nothing more...